# Web app can create a Google Drive Folder, how can it list files inside that it didn't create?

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api, scopes

I'm trying to be a good citizen and use the `drive.file` scope, but I'm hitting some snags and not entirely sure how to work through them.

Overview:

1. user logs into my application, which uses `drive.file` scope
2. my application creates a new Folder in the user's Drive, then creates a File in that folder
3. the user adds new files to that Folder on their own through the Drive interface
4. my application searches that Folder and *only finds the files it created*

**How do I allow my web app to read ALL of the files inside of a folder it has created, not just the files it has also created?**

I had assumed the answer was in the [Permissions API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), that perhaps I would create a new Permission, but the docs don't seem to make sense for an API client. Would it be a "user" type permission? If so, I must provide an email address parameter, but what email address should be used for the client? Would it be a "domain" type permission? What domain would I use? Am I just searching for files wrong, and some option would expose the other files to my app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to retrieve the file list including the files which are not created with the scope of `drive.file` at your app, I think that the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` is required to be added to your current scopes. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth) specifies that `drive.file` gives only `Per-file access to files created or opened by the app`

If you see the descriptions of all other possible scopes, you will relaize that unfortunately there is no such scope that gives you access to all files in a certain folder, but not to any other folder on user's drive.

Thus, the scopes will not help you here.

**If you want to have access only to files in a certain folder, you need to implement a workaround.**

E.g., you can deploy the WebApp as "You" and ask the user to share the folder of interest with you. Then, the WebApp will only have access to the respective folder.

Comment: Thank you! Would you say that it is safe to say something like "API Clients are authorized via scopes, and users are authorized via Sharing/Permissions"? If so, that sentence would have saved me some time banging against the Permissions API, I was thinking scopes were like a baseline and then surely users could opt to share more things with my app if they wanted, but that appears to be a terrible assumption on my part.

Comment: Scopes and permissions are not directly comparable, but I would say that the scopes are the framework within which your app works, while the permissions are the user's tool to restrict/allow access to their individual files.

Comment: Ok maybe I don't get it, yet. Can users "allow" my app to access files it didn't create? If so what is that process? Reading `drive.file` scope it says _"...that you have created or opened with this app."_, what is that talking about when it says "opened"? How would the app open a file it isn't allowed to access? (Sorry I'm not getting it!)

Comment: You are right, the scope `drive.file` gives only access to apps that were created with the App. Other scopes like e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` gives the App reading access to any file on user's drive (unfortunately there is nothing in-between the two extremes).

Comment: In principle this scope is useful, however if the user is not comfortable with giving you reading access to all files on his drive, deploying the WebApp as "you" will only allow the App to read / list files that the user has explicitly shared with you. This is safer for the user's privacy, however requires communication between you and the user as well as action from the user's side.